# Retrieving property cardinalities from an RDF dataset

Tags: sparql, rdf

How would you go about this in SPARQL: **listing the properties used in the dataset together with their respective min/max cardinalities**?

For example, given this sample RDF dataset:

```
@prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .

<https://www.w3.org/People/Berners-Lee/card#i> foaf:familyName "Berners-Lee" ;
  foaf:knows <http://danbri.org/foaf#danbri> ,
    <http://dig.csail.mit.edu/2008/webdav/timbl/foaf.rdf#libby> .

<http://danbri.org/foaf#danbri> foaf:familyName "Brickley" ;
  foaf:knows <http://dig.csail.mit.edu/2008/webdav/timbl/foaf.rdf#libby> .

<http://dig.csail.mit.edu/2008/webdav/timbl/foaf.rdf#libby> foaf:familyName "Miller" .
```

the result should look like this:

| property | minCardinality | maxCardinality |
| --- | --- | --- |
| http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/familyName | 1 | 1 |
| http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/knows | 0 | 2 |

Note that the absence of a property on some of the subjects is treated as `?minCardinality = 0`.

Answer (score 4):

This query:

```
SELECT (?p AS ?property) (MIN(?c) AS ?minCardinality) (MAX(?c) AS ?maxCardinality) 
{
  SELECT ?s ?p (count(?o) AS ?c) {
    { SELECT DISTINCT ?p { [] ?p [] }}
    { SELECT DISTINCT ?s { ?s ?p [] }}
    OPTIONAL { ?s ?p ?o }
  }
  GROUP BY ?s ?p
}
GROUP BY ?p
```

Gives this result (using Jena):

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| property                               | minCardinality | maxCardinality |
============================================================================
| <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/familyName> | 1              | 1              |
| <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/knows>      | 0              | 2              |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Nice John! I added a clarification re. `?minCardinality = 0` but you got this exactly as I wanted :)